# how to string pad with variables instead of hard coded numbers inside %s in java

Tags: java, string, text-alignment

I am trying to pad a string to the right with spaces to make different string lengths align at the same point. I tried using the following in order to do that. However, I cannot figure how I can use the variable namePad be inside the %s as if we worked with real numbers (using %(namePad)s instead of %5s for example)

```
 public String toString() {
    int namePad = 10-name.length();
    return String.format(id + " -" + " %-5s" + "%10s" , name, "");
}
```

output sample:

```
All customers:
1 - Bill Gates          *// padding all the strings to here
2 - Trump           *  
3 - Tali           *            
4 - James Bond          *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `"%-"+namePad+"s"` instead of `"%-5s"`

Although, I am unsure you really need that variable at all. You are using `String.format`, but giving no variables to format, so try this instead.

```
String.format("%d - %-21s", id, name);
```

Or, as before

```
int pad = 21;
return String.format("%d - %-"+pad+"s*", id, name);
```

---

For example, (with the `*` added to show the padding)

```
static class Person {
    int id;
    String name;

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id; this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d - %-21s*", id, name);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Person[] people = { 
        new Person(1, "Bill Gates"),
        new Person(2, "Trump"),
        new Person(3, "Tail"), 
        new Person(4, "James Bond")
    };

    for (Person p : people) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 - Bill Gates           *
2 - Trump                *
3 - Tail                 *
4 - James Bond           *
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot, it didn't work when namePad was 0 but otherwise it did work,
but the second solution was better

Comment: Well, yes, if it is zero, there is no space to print a string